# How to compute the derivative of cosine calculated from cross-product?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

Assume we have two vectors $W \in R^d$ and $X \in R^d$. We can calculate the cosine between the two vectors such that:

$$\frac{W^T*X}{|W|*|X|}$$

I am a bit confused how to calculate the derivative of this expression with respect to X and then W. Can anybody help me out here?

Update:

So I did the calculation based on @J.G. answer and I got the following result:

$$f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}=\frac{\sum_i{W_i*X_i}}{\sqrt{\sum_j{W_j^2}} * \sqrt{\sum_k{X_k^2}}}$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial g(W)}{\partial W_l} = X_l$$
$$\frac{\partial h(W)}{\partial W_l} = \frac{-W_l}{{(\sum_j{W_j^2})}^{3/2}}$$

Then using the Quotient rule

$$\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W_l} = \frac{h(W)*\frac{\partial g(W)}{\partial W_l}-g(W)*\frac{\partial h(W)}{\partial W_l}}{h(W)^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W_l} = \frac{\sqrt{\sum_j{W_j^2}} * \sqrt{\sum_k{X_k^2}}*X_l - \frac{-W_l}{{(\sum_j{W_j^2})}^{3/2}}*\sum_i{W_i*X_i})}{(\sqrt{\sum_j{W_j^2}} * \sqrt{\sum_k{X_k^2}})^2}$$

So we can obtain the gradient with respect to W as follows:

$$\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W} = \frac{|X|*|W|*X - \frac{-W}{|w|^3}\cdot W^TX}{(|W|*|X|)^2}$$

Comment: Your notation is a little confused; I think you meant to write $f=gh$ or $f=g/h$ (as opposed to $f=\partial g/\partial h$). I think you may have mixed up these two in your choice of whether to use the product or quotient rule, because there's an obvious problem with your formula for $\partial_W f$. If vectors $W,\,X$ have the dimension of length then $|X||W|X$ has length dimension 3, but $\frac{W^T X}{W|W|^3}$ (whatever that means) doesn't.

Comment: $\frac{1}{W*|W|^3}$ comes from $\frac{1}{-W_l*{(\sum_j{W_j^2})}^{3/2}}$  I did my best but I cant find the mistake I did.

Comment: DalekSupreme The $W_l$ should be on the top instead.

Comment: @J.G. I modified the equation according to your last suggestion. Is that right now?

Comment: Not quite. You're still differentiating $h$ on the assumption it's proportional to $W^{-1}$, which is inconsistent with its being a quotient instead of a factor. You also forgot to include the quotient's $X$-dependence.

Comment: Should not the X be constant?

Comment: I recommend you differentiate $f\sqrt{\sum_i X_i^2}$ first.

Comment: Is it not 0? It does not have a $W_l$ term. and we differenciate with respect to $W_l$

Comment: Right: $f=g/h$ with $g=W\cdot X$ and $h=\sqrt{\sum_i W_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_i X_i^2}$ so $\partial_{W_l}g=X_l$ and $\partial_{W_l}h=W_l X/W$. Hence $$\partial_{W_l}(g/h)=(hg'-gh')/h^2=(W^2 X X_l-W\cdot X X W_l)/(W^3X^2).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating a scalar $A$ with respect to a vector $\mathbf{B}$ gives a vector whose $i$th entry is obtained by instead differentiating with respect to $B_i$. In this case $A=\dfrac{\sum_i W_i X_i}{\sqrt{\sum_j W_j^2}\sqrt{\sum_k X_k^2}}$, which you can differentiate with respect to either $W_l$ or $X_l$ using the product & chain rules, which I'll lead to you. By symmetry, we only need to do the $W_l$ case; if we get $f_l(\mathbf{W},\,\mathbf{X})$, the derivative with respect to $X_l$ is $f_l(\mathbf{X},\,\mathbf{W})$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helps a lot. However it is still not completely clear how to calcluate the derivative with respect to $B_i$. I tried to do the calculation and I got this: $\frac{df(X,W)}{dX_l} = \frac{\sum_i{W_i*X_i} - W_l*X_l + W_l}{?}$

Comment: @DalekSupreme Here's a hint: $\partial_{W_i}(\sum_j W_j^2)^{-1/2}=-W_i(\sum_j W_j^2)^{-3/2}$.

Comment: Why do you have negative in the power?

Comment: @DalekSupreme Because your original function is proportional to $W^{-1}$.

Comment: I dont really get where the $W_i$ came from. also where did the $\frac{-1}{2}$ go?

Comment: @DalekSupreme Your questions have the same answer! The chain rule introduces a $2W_i$ factor, turning $-\frac{1}{2}$ into $-W_i$.

Comment: I updated my question and I would be pleased if you could have a look and give me some feedback whether it is good or not. I tried to follow your suggestions and do the math.